# AWS recreates an ec2 instance after termination

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-auto-scaling

I created ECS Cluster and it gave me an ec2 instance
When I'm deleting ECS Cluster the ec2 instance didn't delete automatically
After I check Auto Scaling Groups and there is no Auto Scaling Group that responsible for this instance
Every time when I'm trying to delete EC2 instance it recreates new instance automatically after 5 min

If you know the problem please let me know.

Comment: Sounds like the EC2 instance wasn't actually part of the ECS cluster that you deleted. Perhaps it's part of some other ECS cluster or Autoscaling Group, which is why a new instance keeps springing into life after you terminate one.

Comment: But I don't have an auto scaling group in my account

Comment: From the symptoms you report, assuming they're correct, it sounds like you have some process, whether it is AWS-managed or your own automation, that is detecting the lack of compute capacity and launching EC2. Perhaps reviewing CloudTrail Logs will help you identify what is launching EC2.